# Solve this Encoded Text! iLppk scyc, wys ihmgltvihi xm! vKein xfs :H

Tags: cipher

I wonder if you'll be able to reverse this set of words, but first you may want to get a bit shifty!

> iLppk scyc, wys ihmgltvihi xm! vKein xfs :H

**I have given you all the information you need to solve this, it's up to you to find out how!**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From your hint "get shifty", we can assume we need to:

> use a Caesar cipher.

At first, I just found the correct value to shift by trial and error; however, by revisiting this question later I found that:

> the amount of words in the first sentence is 22, therefore we need to use Rot-22.

From this, we can get:

> eHllg oyuy, suo edichprede ti! rGaej tbo :D 
>  You can get this by using Rot-22 on the original string.

Then, from the hint "reverse this set of words", we can tell we need to reverse or swap something. Therefore, we:

> Swap every pair of letters, but keep spaces in their original position. If a letter has no letter to pair with (ignoring spaces), do not swap it. Do not swap characters. "eH"->"He", "ll"->"ll", "g o"->"o g", "yu"->"uy", "y, s"->"s, y", etc.

This results in:

> Hello guys, you deciphered it! Great job :D

Comment: Explain how you got this from the question. Where were the hints that I dropped in the introduction?

Comment: Esrever and ytfihs tib of course...

Comment: All right, I did. Sorry, this is my first answer.

Comment: Why was my question downvoted anyway? I thought the introduction made it quite nice.